# Asynchronous callback flow control

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, control-flow

I'm looking to have better flow control for this async waterfall function.

```
async.waterfall([
  async.apply(osxAppIconName, options.appFile),
  function(iconFileName, callback) {
    var existingIcon = path.join(options.iconDirectory, iconFileName);
    return callback(null, existingIcon);
  },
  async.apply(fs.copy, options.iconFile), //automatically puts in existingIcon
  async.apply(osxAppIconTouch, options.appFile),
], callback);
```

Right now I'm using `async.apply` which will inject global function arguments. In this case above I'm good, it takes `existingIcon` and will add it as the second-to-last argument in `fs.copy`. Making `fs.copy`'s arguments `options.iconfile`, `exitingIcon`, callback `[function]`. Which is great!

However, let's say I need exitingIcon later on. Let's say I push this into my waterfall functions array.

```
async.apply(newFunction, existingIcon)
```

How would I get `existingIcon` to this function? Globals? It seems like a headache to manage! I also think that the `async.apply` function is executing on load, so if I pass it a variable it's gonna use the value of the variable when `async.apply` executes.

Thoughts? I have a proposal for `async.switchboard` [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/672). Which attempts to solve this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Nesting always works.

Comment: @Bergi Are you trolling me?

Comment: I didn't mean to, no. But whenever you need variables multiple times (i.e. not a straight waterfall), then nesting callbacks is the trivial solution which works well (much better than trying to use globals) and usually is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nifty way around this using `async.auto` which attaches the result of a function to a prop in the chain.

```
return async.auto({
  "icon_name": async.apply(osxAppIconName, options.appFile),
  "copy_icon": ["icon_name",
    function(callback, results) {
      results.existing_icon = path.join(options.iconDirectory, results.icon_name);
      return fs.copy(options.iconFile, results.existing_icon, callback);
    }
  ],
  "touch_icon": ["copy_icon", async.apply(osxAppIconTouch, options.appFile)],
}, callback);
```

For promises check out:

- https://github.com/reggi/promise-ripple
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-auto